# @TransactionAttribute cannot resolve symbol in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I wrote a small method:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void assignDepartment(Long departmentId, String pesel) {
        entityManager.createQuery("UPDATE Employee e set departmentId = :departmentId where e.pesel = :pesel")
                .setParameter("departmentId", departmentId)
                .setParameter("pesel", pesel)
                .executeUpdate();
    }
```

but I receive an error `Cannot resolve symbol TransactionAttribute`. Am I missing something in pom.xml?

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spingframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Annotation is required otherwise I have: `Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Spring side it's not `TransactionAttribute`, it's `Transactional`.
So, your method would like like

```
@Transactional( propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW )
public void assignDepartment(Long departmentId, String pesel) {
        entityManager.createQuery("UPDATE Employee e set departmentId = :departmentId where e.pesel = :pesel")
                .setParameter("departmentId", departmentId)
                .setParameter("pesel", pesel)
                .executeUpdate();
}
```

and both `Transactional` and `Propagation` live inside `org.springframework.transaction.annotation`

Comment: Also found that can use:
`EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
        transaction.begin(); transaction.commit()` as there is problem with `@Transactional` annotation with h2 db but answer is correct, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**@Transactional** attribute is used from Spring annotations to denote a single unit of transaction with the database.

Also, you can use JPA's **EntityManager** to perform transactional operations on DB as:

```
Transaction txn= EntityManager.unwrap(Transaction.class);
txn.begin();
//your transactional code
txn.commit();
```